# JBoss5 MainDeployer MBEAN listDeployer returns empty collection

Tags: jboss, pojo, jmx, vfd

It seems that the MainDeployer MBean doesn't work/is not implemented.
how to retrieve the list of deployed application in JBoss 5?

Comment: It does work, and it is implemented. Please post sample code of how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interessted in the JMX MBean View of Web-Console which can be reached using this URL http://localhost:8080/web-console/ as well as JMX-Console http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/
If you bound your jboss using parameter -b to another interface, you need to replace localhost in the URL given above.

Comment: this is not the answer, since the question wasn't about how to access jmx console. I asked about alternative to retrieve information about deployments. it doesn't matter if via POJO or MBEAN